# API call to LinkedIn Test Organizations

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am working on an app that extracts analytic data from different social medias. Both Instagram and Facebook allow you to get this data for your team members without having to approve the app. I am in early stages and just want to play around with the API's to see what data I can get.

From my understanding LinkedIn does not allow a playground or does not allow making API calls to your own organisation for testing. It does have two test organisations found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations). My Understanding was that I could make an API call to these organizations without needing approval for my app or oAuth Token. So I could test the analytics API and their responses. But when I do make the call i get the following error

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 65604,
    "message": "Empty oauth2 access token",
    "status": 401
}
```

I do not have an access token since I dont have access to any scopes so I cant get an access token. If I do enter a random value for access token I get `Invalid access token`

Do I need to get approval for `Marketing Developer Platform` to even make API calls to the test organization ? Is there no way to make test API calls to see the response before applying for a program ? Approval can take upto 90 days and I dont want to run a few tests before that process.